# How do I remove/disable from xValue from showing in the graph when a mouse is hovered?

Tags: javascript, graph, linechart

I am using JSCharting library to draw this line chart and in the line chart when you hover your mouse over the graph you get details about the point which straight above or below your mouse pointer. like this:

[image: picture].

Here is my code for drawing the chart:

```
    JSC.Chart('chartDiv', {
    title_label_text: 'ICryptoWorld Price Chart',
    legend_visible: false,
    type: 'line',
    xAxis_crosshair_enabled: true,
    yAxis: { scale_minorInterval: 25, formatString: 'c' },
    defaultSeries_lastPoint_label_text: '<b>%seriesName</b>',
    defaultPoint_tooltip: `%seriesName : $ <b>%yValue</b>  <br>Date: <b>%zValue<b><br>`,
    series: series
});
```

So, as you see:

[image: picture]

it shows USD and Date but there is also an value above them (In this case it is 1641475802). How do I remove it or disable it from showing?

Answer (score 0):

Since you enable the crosshair, the main tooltip template for all series is under defaultTooltip_label_text and by default is `%xValue %values'. You can change it to just '%values' which will show only the point tooltips.

```
   JSC.Chart('chartDiv', {
    title_label_text: 'ICryptoWorld Price Chart',
    legend_visible: false,
    type: 'line',
    xAxis_crosshair_enabled: true,
    defaultTooltip_label_text:'%values',
    yAxis: { scale_minorInterval: 25, formatString: 'c' },
    defaultSeries_lastPoint_label_text: '<b>%seriesName</b>',
    defaultPoint_tooltip: `%seriesName : $ <b>%yValue</b>  <br>Date: <b>%zValue<b><br>`,
    series: series
});
```

Hope that helps.